# What is the difference between “have to”, “must”, and “should”?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, obligation

Is there any difference between have to”, “must”, and “should”?

If there is some difference between them, when do I have to use (nor not use) each of the constructions below?

- **have to** do something
- **must** do something
- **should** do something

Comment: Related and probable duplicate of: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4425 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/71001 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21706 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/107822 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16462 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/109777 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/40265 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/108451 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/35191 and ***many, many*** more besides that.

Comment: Related: [Deontic “must”, “have to” and “had to”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446403/deontic-must-have-to-and-had-to)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there are differences.
These three [modals](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/modals.html) refer to deontic obligation of various varieties.
Like all modals, they're used in many idioms, all irregular.
And they have different syntax, too.

There have been many dissertations written about modals and necessity/obligation,
so I won't belabor the point here. Well, I'll try not to, anyway.

*Must* and *should* are modal auxiliary verbs, and contrast in their deontic sense in the strength  (and often in the source) of the obligation.
*Must* is stronger; it's used in orders.
*Should* is weaker; it's used in advice.

Plus, quite often, *must* obligations come from outside (fate, weather, boss, parents, mullah -- somebody or something who or which can enforce the order), while *should* obligations come from your own conscience, or from people who seem to care about you.

*Have to* is a modal paraphrase (also called a periphrastic modal, which is "paraphrase" in Greek), of *must*.
[(*Ought to* is a modal paraphrase of *should*. I won't deal with it here.)](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/53250/15299)

Modal paraphrases come in handy in English when we need a past tense or a negative in the sentence, because modal auxiliary verbs have very limited syntax -- they require all negatives to follow them, and they are not inflected for tense.

- *He has to leave now*.  = *He must leave now.*
  Normally, in the present and in the affirmative, they're identical.
  But with a negative, there are two possibilities
- *He doesn't have to leave*. ≠ *He must not leave.*
  The first one means he has no obligation to leave,
  but the second means he has an obligation **not** to leave; i.e, he must stay.
  And with a past obligation, the auxiliary verb just won't stretch.
- *He had to leave at 4pm*.  ≠ **He musted leave at 4pm.*

Comment: I would only add that most people are unfamiliar with the term *deontic*, meaning “Of or relating to duty, obligation, etc.”  Hm, I wonder whether there’s any literature on people being motivated to use things like “be able to” and “have to” so that they can carry tense markers in ways that true modals seldom can.

Comment: _Deontic_ vs _epistemic_ (two kinds of modal meaning) is explained in the link. Every modal expression can be interpreted either way, though there are lots of contexts that force one or the other interpretation. As epistemic modals, _must_ means 'necessary, in my opinion' (_He must be home by now_), while _should_ means 'likely, in my opinion' (_He should be home by now_). _Have to_ still means _must_ epistemically, but it's not as common outside deontic usages.

Comment: By the way, the Deontic-Epistemic opposition was mentioned in a recent [_Lexicon Valley_ podcast](https://slate.com/podcasts/lexicon-valley/2020/07/modal-verbs-future-tense).

Answer (score 3):

Examples

- I have to tell you this - someone/something is making me tell you
- I must tell you this - it is important so I will.
- I should tell you this - if I didn't I would feel bad. I might not actually tell you but I should

Here are more differences

http://www.onestopenglish.com/support/ask-the-experts/grammar-questions/grammar-teaching-the-modals-ought-to-should-must-and-have-to/146365.article

Comment: So Should have not "Important" mode?

Comment: It can be important, but I might not actually do it