# Shift to "must" for negation of "have to"?

Tags: word-usage, negation, dialects, modal-verbs

According to englishpage.com, if *[have to](http://englishpage.com/modals/haveto.html)* or *[must](http://englishpage.com/modals/must.html)* expresses certainty, the negative form uses *must not*. Example:

> That has to be Jerry. They said he was tall with bright red hair.
>   => That must not be Jerry. They said he has blond hair, not red hair.

I learned that *must not* expresses prohibition (and this case is also listed there) and I've never encountered an exception so far. So, it sounded funny to me and I asked a native English speaker. She's of the opinion that this usage of *must not* is not right, but she's only sure about British English.

- Is this usage of *must not* just wrong?
- Or is it correct for a certain variation of English? American English, for instance?
- Or was it correct in former times and nowadays considered archaic?

EDIT:
Many, if not all, answers state that the proper use is *can't*. This, however, is **not** my question. Furthermore, some answers elaborated on the proper meaning of *must not* in the sense of "not allowed to do". This isn't my question either. I must be aware (no pun intended) of the proper meaning of *must not*, otherwise I wouldn't have noticed this 'error'.

---

I don't know nothing about the author of that page but, in dubio pro reo, I assume that they know what they talk about.

Comment: That doesn't have to be Jerry.

Comment: And he must not have to use the loo.

Comment: There are two ways to negate a modal. Say the modal is `Necessary`, like _must_ or _have to_, and the negative is `Not`. Then they can combine into `Not Necessary` (like _don't have to_) or into `Necessary Not` (like _must not_). That's one of the reasons why we have modal paraphrases to go with our modal auxiliary verbs. This, btw, is independent of the Deontic / Epistemic distinction; it's part of the [utter strangeness of the modal system in English](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/126145/15299).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the use of *must* in your quoted example.  It's fine in contemporary English.  Your informant who says it's "not right" is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I agree that "that *can't* be Jerry" is idiomatic, there are times when we do use "must not".

Let's say you're watching a murder mystery.  You get clue after clue, and eventually come to suspect that a particular character is the villain, let's say it's the pharmacist. But then a new clue surfaces, which seems to point suspicion elsewhere. You can say:

**So, it must not *be* the pharmacist.**

The phrase above is spoken *tentatively*, with a questioning intonation, because you are only coming to believe something but are not quite certain.

When you do become certain that the pharmacist is not the murderer (e.g. he's having an affair with the mayor, and they were in Las Vegas at the time, and the two of them are clearly visible on the security TV tapes of the casino at the time of the murder), then you can say:

**So, it *can't* be the pharmacist!**

Comment: I don’t quite follow your example—especially the apparent emphasis on _be_ throws me off, so I can’t quite figure out what effect and tone of voice you’re going for … But more than that, I find “That must not be Jerry, then” a perfectly natural and normal sentence, provided that _must_ is completely unstressed, and _not_ is stressed. Similar to “I’ve never seen that before!” — “Well, you must not have been looking very hard, then, ’cause it’s been there all along.”

Comment: In my dialect, the "aha" is reflected by the stress being placed on "be" rather than on "not" where it might be expected to fall. In my dialect, for a person to say "So, that must not be Jerry" would indicate that it was *dawning on* the speaker that it wasn't Jerry. And you're right, "must" would receive no stress at all in that case.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Are you saying that "That must not be Jerry" (with the meaning "that can't be him") and "you must not have been looking very hard" (with the meaning "you probably didn't look very hard) sounds natural to you? Most, if not all answers, imply that this usage would be wrong; though nobody so far claimed that it indeed were wrong. I'm still waiting for some response that someone is certain that it is wrong or not, for that matter. So, do you say that it is not wrong? May I ask what variation of English you speak?

Comment: @Em1 Yes, I say it's not wrong. It's not as common (nor as natural) as _can’t_ would be, but there's nothing wrong with it. Googling around for some likely phrases with that kind of construction, I found a few quotes from movies and interviews where people were definitely using it in this sense. I'm dialectally confused between BrE and AmE, so I don't know if this works in both or only one of them. Definitely works for me in AmE, though. (See also Jim’s answer which agrees.)

Comment: @TRomano So, does "it must not be the pharmacist" mean "It still may be him, but it doesn't must be him"

Comment: @Em1: it means, it no longer appears to be the pharmacist.

Answer (score 7):

> 1. That has to be Jerry.
> 2. That must be Jerry.
> 3. That can't be Jerry.

*DEONTIC* modality is about what people think is good or right to do or not do. *EPISTEMIC* modality is basically about what we know. We indulge in it when we make judgements about what is, may, or cannot be true.

**Epistemic modality**

The Original Poster's example involves the epistemic use of *HAVE TO*:

- That has to be Jerry.

Here the speaker is saying something along the lines of: from the evidence available I'm deducing that that's definitely Jerry. As far as epistemic modality is concerned, we could get more or less the same reading from the use of *must*:

- That must be Jerry.

Now there's two ways that we might want to negate this statement. We might want to say that it is not necessarily the case that that is Jerry. Technically we could say this by negating the *HAVE TO* sentence:

- That doesn't *have* to be Jerry!

However, this sounds pretty strange in English and we would probably only say this if we were contradicting someone who said *That has to be Jerry*. A more natural sentence would be something like *That's not necessarily Jerry*. Or even *That might be Jerry*. The last sentence doesn't have the same flavour, but actually boils down to the same thing.

On the other hand there is a completely different way to negate this sentence. We may want to reverse the judgement itself but keep the definitiveness involved in the original *HAVE TO* sentence. In other words we might want to say that that is *necessarily not* Jerry according to our evidence. When dealing with negative epistemic statements like this, we do not like to use *mustn't* to rule out a possibility. We have also already seen that *doesn't have to* means *not necessarily* - it doesn't mean *necessarily not* which is what we are after. We need to use *can't* or *cannot* here. So a negation of *That has to be Jerry* in terms of saying that it is necessarily *not* Jerry might be phrased thus:

- That can't be Jerry!

**Deontic modality**

When we move from epistemic modality to deontic modality however, the situation is not the same. Again we see a rough equivalence between *MUST* and *HAVE TO*:

- You have to leave the area.
- You must leave the area.

Again if we want to say that something is not necessary, we can use *not have to*:

- You don't have to leave the area.

But if we want to say that it's necessary that you don't do something we use *mustn't*:

- You mustn't leave the area.

Notice that we couldn't really achieve the same meaning using *mustn't* when dealing with epistemic modality. In that situation we used *cannot* or *can't*. We can use the same thing here too, although the sentence may be ambiguous:

- You can't leave the area.

**Conclusion**

We use *HAVE TO* and *MUST* for both deontic and epistemic necessity. However, to express a lack of necessity we use *not have to*. With epistemic judgements we are most likely to use *can't* to express that a proposition is necessarily not true. With deontic judgements we use *mustn't* to express that something necessarily not be done.

The example from the EFL site in the Original Poster's example is a bit strange for many readers. The reason is it uses *mustn't* for epistemic modality where we would expect *can't*. This does, having corresponded with some US speakers here, seem to be more specifically the case in GB English.

*Hope this is helpful!*

---

**Edit note on epistemic *mustn't***

Notice that I said above that we do not "like to" use *mustn't* to rule out a possibility.

I didn't say that we can't. The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* Huddleston & Pullum *et al* 2002, state that although we sometimes use *mustn't* epistemically, it ...

> ... is quite rare and restricted (indeed unacceptable for many speakers): in negative contexts *must* and *need* are usually interpreted deontically. (pp. 180-1)

The thrust of this is that some speakers will just not give *mustn't* an epistemic reading, but that some other speakers *do* use it - although only in restricted environments.

Several writers here who speak varieties of US English have said that they believe this is much more acceptable in US English than it is in British English. It seems highly likely, therefore, that there is a difference in the acceptability of *mustn't* for epistemic modality between British and American Englishes.

Thank you to F.E. and JanusBahsJacquet for their input, and direction to relevant sources here.

Comment: Have a look at Jim’s answer, too—there's more to this story than meets the eye, it would seem. The fact that you (BrE) quite categorically speak against epistemic _must not_, while Jim (AmE) speaks for it convinces me that the part of my brain that thinks this is a perfectly natural and fine construction must be the AmE part. And also that Jim is correct in deeming this a Br-Am difference, which I for one never knew it was.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Hmm, have done some rummaging and got some advice from both you and F.E. and there does indeed seem to be a bit a pond thing here. Am also going to add some stuff from CaGEL to clarify about the BE. I originally put *don't like to* in the body, but waas less equivocal in the conclusion. There are times when we use this in BE, although it's much rarer. Thanks for the input! :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Does the above seem better to you now?

Comment: Absolutely! (I can't stop getting that damn Beyoncé song stuck in my head every time I see this question now, argh!)

Answer (score 2):

This is a British-English/US-English issue:

**Not OK in UK**
Cambridge sounds the high alarm in *[English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/must)*

> Warning:
> We use can’t/cannot as the negative of must to deny something or make negative deductions or conclusions:
>
> *It just can’t be true. He can’t have left his job.*
>
> *That cannot be his sister. She looks so different.*

But us rebels use *must not* for *probably not* or *logic implies it can't be/is unlikely*:

Song: *[You must not be drinking enough](http://www.metrolyrics.com/you-must-not-be-drinking-enough-lyrics-earl-thomas-conley.html)*

[Tweet:](https://twitter.com/shesolay/status/509833697197973504) *This must not be her first time getting her ass whooped by him.*

[Restaurant review](http://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowUserReviews-g59929-d827642-r126788360-Josephine_s_Pizza_Pastaria-Green_Bay_Wisconsin.html) “Must not be what it used to be” ...
I went to Josephines this past week and was shocked to see how in the past month things could go from good to terrible.

Comment: This is exactly the usage I had in mind in my comment on TRomano’s answer. To my mind, _must not_ and _cannot_ differ slightly in meaning: with _must not_, circumstances prove positively that it is only possible that X is not the case; with _cannot_, circumstances prove negatively that it is not possible that X is the case. “He can't have left yet” = it is not possible he has left yet. “He must not have left yet” = it must be that he has not left yet. Amounting to the same thing, but still meaning slightly different things.

Comment: Also—and how odd nobody’s thought of this before—[Beyoncé](http://lyrics.wikia.com/Beyoncé:Irreplaceable).

Comment: I have a new song in my head: *with must not, circumstances prove positively that it is only possible that X is not the case; with cannot, circumstances prove negatively that it is not possible that X is the case.* O.O

Answer (score 1):

I can hardly resist posting the quaintly self-referential statement

> *must* [= logical necessity] cannot normally be used in interrogative or negative clauses

apparently from *A comprehensive grammar of the English language* (Quirk, Greenbaum, Leech, Svartvik, 1985). I haven't got the book, sadly, and this is a quotation found online in *English Corpus Lingustics* (Aijmer, Altenberg, 2014), p. 156; the latter also somewhat disputes the statement, leaning on usage of American undergraduates, who tend to occasionally use *must not* epistemically.

The modality in the example sentence is *epistemic* (expressing how certain the speaker is of the statement):

- *That has to be Jerry.*  (*That must be Jerry.*)
- (normal) opposite *That cannot be Jerry.*

As opposed to a *deontic* use of 'must':

- *You must wear gloves (it's cold)*.
- (negation) *You need not wear gloves (it's quite warm).*
- (opposite) *You must not wear gloves (you'll need your fingers).*

Exactly as you say, *must not* in the second set of statements expresses a prohibiton. (*Normally...*) Normality is exactly what I'd expect in the context of grammar examples at englishpage.com.

Answer (score 1):

**That must not be Jerry**

This usage suggests that I may be wrong (i.e. I'm not 100% confident it's Jerry).  It can also suggest that I am expressing agreement to something I thought previously not to be the case (ie *that must be Jerry **after all*** (contrary to what I first thought))

Compare this to

**That can't be Jerry**

which expresses my confident opinion.  I know about Jerry and this person is not Jerry.

Answer (score 0):

*Must not* does indeed sound strange in this case.

The switch to *must* happens in case you actually are talking about an obligation to start with:

> You have to sign your name on every page.

Which is equivalent to

> You must sign your name on every page.

However,

> You don't have to sign your name on every page.

Means that you are allowed to sign, but it's OK if you don't, whereas

> You must not sign your name on every page.

Means that it is *not* OK if you do it!

In the sentence that you used, there is no obligation, but an *expectation*.

> That has to be Jerry! (or, That must be Jerry!)

Means: in all likelihood, based on our information and observations, I'd say there is a very high chance that that person, indeed, is Jerry.

In this case, using *must* in a negative way sounds off.

> That must not be Jerry.

Sounds as if someone that might be Jerry is coming along, but I really have a strong wish that it be someone else. (Maybe he is about to walk in on our preparations for his surprise party). The sentence does not really sound natural though.

> That doesn't have to be Jerry.

This would mean that that person we see there might be Jerry, but it might be someone else. Yes, he's tall and his hair is red, but that doesn't mean the first tall redhead we see is Jerry.

To express the opposite of "that has to be Jerry!" in the context that you quoted, a more natural way would be:

> No, that **can't** be Jerry. They said Jerry was blond, this guy's red.

Comment: As others have clarified, there's absolutely nothing wrong with "That must not be Jerry" on this side of the pond. Also, it means something slightly different than "That can't be Jerry": "must not" implies some level of incredulity and/or uncertainty. (Of course, "can't" isn't 100% certain either -- otherwise, you'd have said "That isn't Jerry" -- and it can be used to imply surprise, too -- "That *can't* be your daughter, she was just a baby yesterday!" -- so it's all very vague and wishy-washy.)