# Can "must not" be used alternately to "can't" in AE to say that sth is logically impossible?

Tags: american-english, word-usage, colloquialisms

Does American English allow the use of "must not" instead of "can't" to say that something is believed to be logically impossible?

Please consider the following examples:

*It must not be true!*

*How can you say such a thing? You must not be serious!* (-you gotta be kidding!)

A: *Joe wants something to eat.*
B: *But he just had lunch. He must not be hungry already.*
(-it's impossible that he is hungry because he just had lunch)

*I just bought a box of cereal yesterday. It must not be empty already.*

*You just started filling out your tax forms 10 minutes ago. You must not be finished with them already?*

*If A is bigger than B, and B is bigger than C, then C must not be bigger than A.*

Comment: I can't say the usage is *wrong*, per se ... but I would not have phrased any of those statements that way, and I would notice if someone else did.

Comment: Elian... ***welcome back!!!*** :))

Comment: "Cannot be true", taken literally, means that "it" (the item in question) is provably false.  "Must not be true", on the other hand, implies that either the speaker does not want "it" to be true, or that there is some prohibition (perhaps in the instructions for a form) of "it" being true.  But these terms are often used "loosely".

Comment: (And the sense of the terms changes somewhat when you slip into subjunctive mood.)

Comment: This issue was discussed recently, including the BrE/AmE distinction. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226936/shift-to-must-for-negation-of-have-to  It was rather inconclusive, except that a few native speakers of AmE agreed that epistemic _must not_  was just fine with them.

Comment: A lot of these read to me like the *must* in *must be nice...* - that is, it doesn't indicate so much that something is the case as it does that something is hypothetically accepted as factual. You'd say your first example after seeing indirect evidence against some claim; the second upon realizing a friend is joking; you'd not say the third; the fourth, somewhat awkwardly, after picking up a cereal box you expected to be empty; etc. In other words, "must" can mean something like "turns out to happen to indeed be the case that".

Comment: The only example that makes sense to me (and means more or less what you want it to mean) is "You must not be serious". The rest simply don't make any sense: "must not" is either a moral obligation, but a cereal box doesn't have moral obligations; or it's a statement of physical laws, but saying that an observably-empty cereal box must not be so is absurd.

Comment: I would add that in maths, the final "If A is bigger than B, and B is bigger than C, then C must not be bigger than A." is completely correct usage. In this limited context, for this one sentence, "cannot" and "must not" are interchangeable.

Comment: In mathematics, modals have only epistemic senses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're asking about is called the ***Epistemic*** sense of a modal.

Every modal auxiliary verb that's still used in English has at least two senses:

1. The **Epistemic** sense, which has to do with logic and perceived probability
   *This may/might be the place ~ This must/should be the place ~ This could be the place.*
2. The **Deontic** sense, which has to do with permission and obligation
   *You may/might kiss his ring now ~ You must/should kiss his ring now.*

In addition, there is an **Alethic** sense, which has to do with personal ability, and shows up only with *can*.  E.g, *He can bench-press 150 kg* means 'He is able to bench-press 150 kg', which obviously entails that it is logically possible but attributes this possibility to the subject rather than to logic.

That's general. Specifically, modals are irregular as hell, and *must* and *can* are more so than usual. 
In addition, all modals interact with negatives, but not in the same ways. Again, they're different.

In American English (UK Englishes vary), epistemic *can* occurs only in a negative environment.
 *This can't be the place ~ This can't be true*, **but not** 
**This can be the place* ~ **This can be true.*
I.e, epistemic *can* is a Negative Polarity Item (NPI). In American English, at least.

*Can,* outside negative environments, usually takes an Alethic sense instead of an Epistemic one,
but it's equally common as equivalent to Epistemic *may* 'permitted to'.
 *You can/may leave* 'You are permitted to leave'.

Epistemic *must* is not an NPI, but it has a specific meaning with *not*.
 *You must not go to the ball* means 'You are **obliged not to go** to the ball'.
It does **not** mean 'You are **not obliged to go** to the ball'.
Logically, that's `Not (Possible (Go (You, Ball)))`.

On the other hand, the periphrastic modal *have to*, which means *must* in the affirmative,
 (*You have to leave now = You must leave now* 'You are obliged to leave now'),
means 'You are **not obliged to leave** now' in the negative,
and not 'You are **obliged not to leave** now'.
Logically, that's `Possible (Not (Go (You, Ball)))`.

So, to answer the original question, Yes. I.e, since they're both negative, *can't* and *must not* both negate possibility (i.e, `Not (Possible (P))` instead of `Possible (Not (P))`) in their epistemic senses, so they're equivalent.

Of course, the differences among logical possibility, personal ability, and official permissions can be very complex and hard to distinguish, so there are -- Surprise! -- exceptions. Just like everything else about modals, negatives, and quantifiers (these are logically Operators, which have logical superpowers of binding foci).

Comment: This is a very interesting answer.  Where could one read more about these senses?

Comment: Well, this is a logical concept, so start with the [Logic Study Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf), and follow it with the [Verb Phrase Study Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf), which deals with auxiliaries. Modals specifically are covered [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf) and [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html); and negation [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf). And here's some [links from ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+modal+epistemic+deontic) dealing with the senses.

Answer (score 5):

The interchangeable use of "must not" for "can't" in colloquial American English seems most natural (and appropriate) to me when, for example, both "[the person] must not" and "[the person] can't" stand for a longer idea amounting to "it must be the case that [the person] does [or did] not." For example, a person seeing that someone has smashed a glass pane in the front door of a house—presumably in order to unlock the door from the inside—might say

> The burglar must not have noticed that the key was in the keyhole of the door.

or equivalently

> The burglar can't have noticed that the key was in the keyhole of the door.

because both wordings convey the logical reasoning:

> It must be the case that the burglar did not notice that the key was in the outside keyhole.

In other situations, however, *must not* and *can't* carry different implications. For example,

> It can't be true!

when viewed in isolation, may be read as a distressed denial of something that may very well be true but is most unwelcome (although under other circumstances it may not). In contrast,

> It must not be true!

carries a triumphant note of certainty appropriate to stating a logical conclusion. Though both expressions are applicable to an array of situations, their implications differ in many settings.

A further complication involves wordings that function as set phrases. For example, the expression

> You can't be serious!

is common as a dismissive exclamation meaning "I don't believe it." But

> You must not be serious!

is not widely used in that sense, so it is more likely to be understood as the conclusion reached at the end of a logical appraisal of something said than as an out-of-hand rejection of the thing said.

And finally, some expressions show very little overlap in meaning between the "must not" form and the "can't" form. For example,

> Such freedom of choice can't be permitted.

strongly implies that the freedom of choice in question poses an existential threat to whatever authority opposes it. To the contrary,

> Such freedom of choice must not be permitted.

expresses categorical opposition, but merely as a matter of policy, to permitting a particular freedom of choice that may already exist.