# What is the use of would in below sentences?

Tags: would

*I would suggest this.*

*It would be great if you complete this.*

Comment: Please [edit] this to show what research you have done to try to answer this question yourself.

Answer (score 2):

*Would* is a **[Modal Auxiliary Verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/275686/15299)**, as are *will, may, might, can, could, shall, should,* and *must*.
As their name suggests, *would* and all other modal auxiliary verbs are used as auxiliary verbs.

An auxiliary verb is a verb that's used to introduce another predicate, usually another verb form. **Modal** auxiliary verbs must be the first auxiliary verb of any verb phrase they occur in, and must  introduce (and be followed by) a verb in its **infinitive** form (but without *to*). [See here](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/VPguide.pdf) for details.

In the sentences given above, *would* is followed by the infinitives *suggest* and *be*;
*be* itself is also an auxiliary verb, required by the predicate adjective *great*.

Comment: Do you mean there are two auxiliary verbs in "It would be great" and the sentence works? Two auxiliary verbs + adjective in a sentence. Then why do we use [*auxiliary verb*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb)? You don't agree with the definition in the link that says *auxiliary verb* is said to help a main verb.

Comment: @Rathony - Yes, there are two auxiliary verbs in _It would be great_.  The _be_ is the auxiliary verb that's used for predicates that aren't verbs, like predicate adjectives (as here). The link doesn't say auxiliary verbs must help a main verb; it says they usually accompany a main verb. And they do. But they can also accompany non-verbal predicates.

Answer (score 0):

In short, in the examples given in the original post, the *would*-construction is typically interpreted as being used to soften or make indirect, perhaps with the goal of making polite speech.

Answer (score -1):

It's the past tense of **will**, in:

If you ask me, I **will** say....

That is, had you *asked me*, I ***would*** have said...